# Basic DRUPAL send data from external site

Tags: php, rest, api, drupal, drupal-7

I have never used Drupal before and have been asked to send data from a form on "website A" to a Drupal site, I have set up Services module and have my endpoint. dose anyone have a simple html or php form i can use to send data to this endpoint ?

do I POST data to http://localhost/communicator-app/bensapi/node ?

[image]

Comment: Your are using service module that is enough. Create your own custom REST API by using service module for POST request. For how to create custom service see this : https://www.drupal.org/node/783460

Comment: Thanks I already have this link open, but it is a useful one :) I was hoping there was a simple form i could create that will send data of to the node endpoint I have made through services.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of clients that will let you create REST calls to test services. You don't need a special app/form to do it. Chrome has a couple, and there is one called [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/) that I've heard some good things about, but I haven't had a chance to use it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most common tool for this sort of thing is [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/). Personaly I use [Paw](https://paw.cloud/), it a bit more powerful. I've not looked at Insomnia.

You could also look at [Apiary](https://apiary.io/) it's got a REST client build in and is a great way to document your API.

Comment: Thanks @mediaashley, Ill look into this